# How can use Repeater control for Image slider control?

Tags: asp.net

I want fetch some images from database and show that images through Image slider.
For that purpose I want to use repeater control.
Please can you say what is the easy way to make use of repeater for Image slider.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way tom implement the repeater for your slider :

```
    <!--Your repeater with the <img /> tags for your slider (can be <li><img /></li> or other pattern)-->
    <asp:Repeater ID="RptImages" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSourceMention">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <img src='<%# Eval("ImgPath") %>' alt="image-slider" />
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>

    <!--Your data source using stored procedure for this sample-->
    <!--The "ConnectionString" attribute is set in your web.config file-->
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSourceImages" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:YourconnectionString %>"
        SelectCommand="YourStoredProcedureName" SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure"></asp:SqlDataSource>
```

This will output a list of  tags with the src attribute bound on the "ImgPath" column of your stored procedure result.